# including bullet points for XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, points

I have XML document and one tag has a long description so I want to format it in several bullet points

for example,

```
<description>This course is an introduction to the information technologies required for secure, practical information systems for electronic commerce.
Topics will be chosen from areas such as document representation (XML, DTDs, XML Schema, XSLT, CSS), security (encryption, public key, symmetric key, 
PKI, authentication); kinds of attack and vulnerabilities, electronic trading (spontaneous, deliberative, auctions), electronic document management 
(metadata, search, digital libraries, management and processing), recent developments and maturation of the area, 
such as web application frameworks, web services, the semantic web , mobile commerce</description>
```

and I want this to be in some what like

- This course is an introduction to the information technologies
  required for secure, practical information systems for electronic
  commerce.
- Topics will be chosen from areas such as document representation
  (XML, DTDs, XML Schema, XSLT, CSS), security (encryption, public key,
  symmetric key, PKI, authentication); kinds of attack and
  vulnerabilities, electronic trading (spontaneous, deliberative,
  auctions),
- electronic document management (metadata, search, digital libraries, 
  management and processing), recent developments and maturation of the
  area, such as web application frameworks, web services, the semantic 
  web , mobile commerce

to do this I believe that I should change something in my XSL file, which is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Course Catalogue </title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FF9999">
        <xsl:for-each select="xsi:catalogue/xsi:course">
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:title" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:year" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:science" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:area" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:subject" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:unit" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:description" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:outcomes" />
            <br />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="xsi:incompatibility" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

and for xsi:description,

```
<!-- The template for course description --> 
<xsl:template match="xsi:description">
    <div style="font-family:times;font-size:16">
        <span style="color:#000"> 
            Course Description: 
        </span> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

How should I include the bullet points? Thank you!

Comment: I have added <li> inside the xslt file but it returned an error nor it did not work on XML file directly..

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried (with `<li>`)? And specify what the error said? And what "did not work" means? And can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you stuck with 1.0?

Comment: I put <li> inside the xml file and the tag <description> (defined in the XML Schema) with the namespace = http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml (like li xmlns="http://~~~") and then it returned: element li: schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}li': No matching global element declaration available, but demanded by the strict wildcard.

Comment: @JaneDoe, Please, edit the question and provide the rules for splitting the text into bullets -- I don't see any obvious explanation why the text should be split in the way you have shown us.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to decide on delimiters to split your description into bullets. Here is an example that splits using period and semicolon as delimeters:

#### Template:

```
<xsl:template match="xsi:description">
    <div style="font-family:times;font-size:16">
        <span style="color:#000">Course Description:</span> 
        <ul>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="string()" regex=".*?[\.;]" flags="sm">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </ul>            
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

#### Output:

```
<div style="font-family:times;font-size:16">
    <span style="color:#000">Course Description:</span>
    <ul>
        <li>This course is an introduction to the information technologies required for secure, practical information systems for electronic commerce.</li>
        <li>Topics will be chosen from areas such as document representation (XML, DTDs, XML Schema, XSLT, CSS), security (encryption, public key, symmetric key, PKI, authentication);</li>
        <li> kinds of attack and vulnerabilities, electronic trading (spontaneous, deliberative, auctions), electronic document management (metadata, search, digital libraries, management and processing), recent developments and maturation of the area, such as web application frameworks, web services, the semantic web , mobile commerce</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can change the regex value from `.*?[\.;]` to something else if you want to use different rules for breaking up the paragraph.